# How do I move the view of the code free around?

Tags: visual-studio-code

in Version 1.82 there is a video shown new sticky scroll feature.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_sticky-scroll

At second 8 in the video, you can see that the code view moves free around.

How is this possible, does anyone know?

- Search for Hotkeys in Keyboard bindings
- Tried shift, ctrl and alt key kombinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the options you need to change, you can keep the other `stickyScroll` options by default:

```json
    "editor.stickyScroll.scrollWithEditor": false,
    "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true,
```

In the video, the behavior is obtained by pressing and releasing the shift button while scrolling. When you press it, it scrolls to the right, when you release, it scrolls to the bottom. In the demo it is just done very quickly so the behavior seems fluid.

Split your window to the right for better observation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It must be the shift key that leaded to that behavior. Sad that there is no other hotkey for overviewing the code as I thought. May this will come one day :-)